# Python Code Classes Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.x, classes, tkinter

I am learning to write my codes accordingly with functions and classes. My original code can create a graphic interface that interacts with different functions. As I said before, I am trying to write it better and I do not know the correct way. I leave the code to correct to see if someone can help me to execute it. I clarify that I work with Python 2.7.

At the momment I have this error:

> TypeError: __init __ () takes exactly 1 argument (2 given).

```
# coding=utf-8
# encoding=utf8
"""..."""
import sys
from tkinter import*
import tkinter as tk
import csv
import pandas as pd
import os
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')


class Shark:
    """."""

    def __init__(self):
        """."""
        self.b = "Working.csv"
        """Nueva Ventana."""
        global ventana
        self.ventana = Tk()
        """Dimenciones de la ventana."""
        self.ventana.geometry("1100x900+0+0")
        """Titulo."""
        self.ventana.title("CSV TOOLS")
        """Texto."""
        self.lblUsuario = Label(text="Bienvenidos a CSV Tools", font=("Agency FB", 22)).place(x=10, y=10)
        """Cargar CSV."""
        self.lblUsuario = Label(text="Cargar CSV", font=("Agency FB", 14)).place(x=10, y=100)
        """Campo de texto."""
        self.entradaU = StringVar()
        self.txtUsuario = Entry(ventana, textvariable=entradaU).place(x=10, y=150)
        self.aceptar = Button(ventana, text="   Aceptar   ", command=self.aceptar, font=("Agency FB", 10)).place(x=210, y=148)

    def aceptar(self):
        """."""
        global a
        self.a = entradaU.get()
        if self.a == "exit":
            raise SystemExit
        else:
            pass
        try:
            with open(self.a, 'rb') as f:
                self.reader = csv.reader(f)
                global lista2
                self.lista2 = list(reader)
                self.lstmaterias = Label(ventana, text="Cabeceras:                                  ").place(x=10, y=180)
                self.lstmaterias = Listbox(ventana, width=100, height=10)
                global lista22
                self.lista22 = ' '.join(str(e) for e in lista2[0])
                self.lstmaterias.insert(0, lista22)
                self.lstmaterias.place(x=10, y=200)
                global entrada2
                self.entrada2 = StringVar()
                self.lstmaterias222 = Label(ventana, text="Filtro").place(x=10, y=400)
                global txtusuarijjo
                self.txtusuarijjo = Entry(ventana, textvariable=entrada2).place(x=10, y=420)
                self.filtro = Button(ventana, text="   Aceptar   ", command=orden, font=("Agency FB", 10)).place(x=210, y=420)

        except IOError:
            lstmaterias = Label(ventana, text="Error:").place(x=10, y=180)
            lstmaterias = Label(ventana, text="Archivo No Encontrado").place(x=40, y=180)

    def orden(self):
        """."""
        global a_orden
        self.a_orden = entrada2.get()
        if self.a_orden == "exit":
            raise SystemExit
        if len(entrada2.get()) == 0:
            return self.a_orden
        if self.a_orden not in self.lista22:
            self.a_orden

        else:
            if self.a_orden in self.lista22:
                self.entrada3 = StringVar()
                self.lstmaterias = Label(self.ventana, text="Ascendente:").place(x=350, y=400)
                self.lstmaterias = Label(self.ventana, text="(True - Flase)").place(x=350, y=450)
                self.txtusuario = Entry(self.entana, textvariable=entrada3).place(x=350, y=420)
                self.true_false = Button(self.ventana, text="   Aceptar   ", command=self.valores, font=("Agency FB", 10)).place(x=550, y=420)
                global f
                self.f = entrada3.get()
                global entrada4
                self.entrada4 = StringVar()
                self.lstmaterias = Label(self.ventana, text="Cantidad de datos:").place(x=700, y=400)
                self.txtusuario = Entry(self.ventana, textvariable=self.entrada4).place(x=700, y=420)
                self.true_false = Button(self.ventana, text="   Aceptar   ", command=self.top, font=("Agency FB", 10)).place(x=900, y=420)

    def top(self):
        """."""
        self.nn = self.entrada4.get()
        self.nn = int(self.nn)
        self.movies = self.pd.read_csv(self.b, nrows=self.nn)
        self.movies = self.movies.to_csv(b, index=False)

    def valores(self):
        """."""
        self.movies = self.pd.read_csv(self.a, error_bad_lines=False, delimiter=',', encoding="utf-8-sig", low_memory=False)
        self.movies = self.movies.sort_values(self.a_orden, ascending=f)
        self.movies = self.movies.to_csv(self.b, index=False)
        global entrada5
        self.entrada5 = StringVar()
        self.lstmaterias = Label(self.ventana, text="Nombre del Archivo Nuevo:").place(x=10, y=500)
        self.txtusuario = Entry(self.ventana, textvariable=self.entrada5).place(x=10, y=520)
        self.true_false = Button(self.ventana, text="   Aceptar   ", command=self.new_csv, font=("Agency FB", 10)).place(x=210, y=520)
        global entrada6
        self.entrada6 = StringVar()
        self.lstmaterias2 = Label(self.ventana, text="Introduzca las Cabeceras:").place(x=350, y=500)
        self.txtusuario2 = Entry(self.ventana, textvariable=entrada6).place(x=350, y=520)
        self.true_false2 = Button(self.ventana, text="   Aceptar   ", command=cabex, font=("Agency FB", 10)).place(x=550, y=520)

    def new_csv(self):
        """."""
        global a_valor
        self.a_valor = entrada5.get()
        if self.a_valor == "exit":
            raise SystemExit

    def cabex(self):
        """."""
        global a_cabex
        self.a_cabex = self.entrada6.get()
        self.a_cabex = self.a_cabex.split()
        with open(self.b, 'r') as self.csvfile, open(self.a_valor, "w") as self.output:
            self.reader = self.csv.DictReader(self.csvfile)
            self.writer = self.csv.DictWriter(self.output, fieldnames=self.a_cabex, extrasaction='ignore')
            self.writer.writeheader()
            for self.row in self.reader:
                self.a = 'fillRate'
                if self.a in self.lista2[0]:
                    self.row['fillRate'] = '{:.2f}'.format(float(self.row['fillRate']) * 100)
                self.writer.writerow(row)
        self.os.remove(b)

        self.lstmsss = Label(self.ventana, text="Reporte Creado", font=("Agency FB", 30)).place(x=350, y=600)


def main():
    """Set name of Shark object."""
    sammy = Shark("Martin Bouhier")
    sammy.aceptar()
    sammy.orden()
    sammy.top()
    sammy.valores()
    sammy.new_csv()
    sammy.cabex()
    ventana.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

input()
```

Comment: This will be hard to review for some, since not all of us are [Spanish speakers](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3795/should-code-be-forcibly-translated-into-english),

Comment: "For now I have this error: TypeError:" Broken code is off topic

Comment: @Ludisposed the comments are not necessary to understand the code

Comment: Your "code" is necessary to understand the code ==> `global ventana` I don't know what this is

Comment: Ventana is a variable... global is to use it in another functions!

Comment: I know what globals are, and much use of that does imply you could learn after finishing your code. I mean that you name a lot of variables in spanish which makes it gibberish for me, and thus unreviewable.

Comment: I think you should post here [es.SO](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) Since this is broken

Comment: oh sorry! I'm new on python and programmer codes so my apologies for that. The Original code is here if you want to see how it is working: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wt6g8yL-tW2rllDYYn9H58U1CmnDp__9/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1) When you define `__init__` method of a `class` in Python, you automatically have `self` argument, which is not written explicitly in function call (e.g. look at [documentation example](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects)).

To specify the argument the way you want, you need to make `__init__(self, shark_name)` and call it as `sammy = Shark("Martin Bouhier")`.

Note that this argument `shark_name` will be accessible in `__init__` constructor, so you can save it in field, for example (`self.name = shark_name`).

2) You have another problem:

`self.txtUsuario = Entry(ventana, textvariable=entradaU).place(x=10, y=150)`

is to be replaced with

`self.txtUsuario = Entry(ventana, textvariable=self.entradaU).place(x=10, y=150)`

You have no local variable `entradaU`, only a field with such name. The same goes for `entrada3` and others - the interpreter will tell you.

3) You mix up field and local variable (namely, `ventana`). Every object of `Shark` has its own instance of `ventana`, which can have different values. If you want a static variable in your class, you should define @staticmethod setter and getter for this field.

4) I suggest you work on your code style as well: pay special attention to [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) - classical code style guide for Python. Furthermore, I see no meaning in comments like `"""."""`, field named `b` in `Shark` class, `true_false` Button looks very confusing, etc. I suggest you google some best practices for Python.

5) As mentioned earlier, you would greatly benefit if your code had been purely English: many developers in the world would find your code clearer. Not to mention all employers and possible colleagues who can only speak English - you will face the necessity of good written English (including code) in very close future.